# Can't read excel files, using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a list of excel files with similar last row. It contains private information about client (his name, surname, phone). Each excel file corresponds to a client. I need to make one excel file with all data about every client. I decide to do it automatically, so looked to `openpyxl` library. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl.styles
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

path_kit = 'prize_input/kit'

#creating single document
prize_info = Workbook()
prize_sheet = prize_info.active

file_array_reciever = []

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_kit, '*.xlsx')):
    file_array_reciever.append(file)

row_num = 1
for f in file_array_reciever:
    f1 = load_workbook(filename=f)
    sheet = f1.active
    for col_num in range (3, sheet.max_column):
        prize_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num).value = \
            sheet.cell(row=sheet.max_row, column=col_num).value

    prize_info.save("Ex.xlsx")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zkid18/PycharmProjects/untitled/excel_test.py", line 43, in <module>
    f1 = load_workbook(filename=f)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 183, in load_workbook
    wb.active = read_workbook_settings(archive.read(ARC_WORKBOOK)) or 0
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1229, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1252, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1196, in getinfo
    'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/workbook.xml' in the archive"
```

Looks like it is a problem with reading file.
I don't understand where it gets an item named `'xl/workbook.xml'` in the archive.

Comment: Maybe one of the excel files is corrupted or uses a feature not supported by openpyxl.

Comment: Make sure the file paths are correct, you can print out 'f' in each loop iteration to confirm.

Comment: There is almost certainly a problem with the file you're trying to read.

Comment: The problem is with the `f1 = load_workbook(filename=f)` line. Put a `print('opening "{}"'.format(f))` in front of that line to determine the name of the problem file so you'll know which one it is. At that point, trying opening the file in Excel to see if it's corrupt.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:**
I have overcome this issue by adding `read_only=True`: Specifically, replace

`f1 = load_workbook(filename=f)` with

`f1 = load_workbook(filename=f, read_only=True)`

Note: Depending on your code,`read_only=True` can make your code *very* slow. If this is the case for you, you may want to try option 2.

**Option 2:** Open your problematic workbook in excel, and then re-save it as a `Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (*.xlsx)`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version you are using, this could be a bug in openpyxl. For example, in 1.6.1 a bug was introduced exhibiting this behavior. Reverting to 1.5.8 fixed it. There was a fix according to this openpyxl [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/160/invalidfileexception-for-missing-theme-161); though the ticket doesn't say when the fix was delivered, it was committed in early 2013. I upgraded to 1.6.2 and the error went away.

Comment: Why the downvote? Upgrading my version of openpyxl is exactly what got rid of the KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/workbook.xml' in the archive", which started appearing when I upgraded from 1.5.8 to 1.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post searching for a solution to a similar issue,
`("There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive")`

None of this error message makes any sense in terms of my script or the file.
My script adds 1 sheet and updates five more in an existing Excel document. 
While my script was running, I realized I had an error in my code. I canceled my script mid-running.

After canceling, the existing Excel file exhibited this error.
Working out bugs with the script, maybe you corrupted your Excel file??

To address this, I'm thinking of creating a temporary restore file in the event of an error using OpenPyXl.

Answer (score 1):

I has the same issue, make sure the file you're trying to read isn't open in Excel already

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlrd biblioteque

This script allow you to transform a excel data to list of dictionnaries

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('your_file.xlsx')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('your_file.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first_row = [] # The row where we stock the name of the column
for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
    first_row.append( worksheet.cell_value(0,col) )
# tronsform the workbook to a list of dictionnary
data =[]
for row in range(1, worksheet.nrows):
    elm = {}
    for col in range(worksheet.ncols):
        elm[first_row[col]]=worksheet.cell_value(row,col)
    data.append(elm)
print data
```

Comment: xlrd does support XLSX files. This isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your file is .xls format before, you can use

```
try:
    f1 = load_workbook(filename=f)
except:
    print f
```

to find which file cause this error and reopen it in Excel, then save as .xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

If openpyxl still doesn't work, using pandas works.

```
$ pip install pandas xlrd
```

And this code works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
```

Comment: I read with pandas but got the same error